# ERROR: WITHIN GROUP is required for ordered-set aggregate mode

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have been using Postgres (version 9.2 and 9.3) with this function: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Mode for a while. Now recently after upgrading to version 9.4 I run into the following error when using the function:

> ```
> PG::WrongObjectType: ERROR:  WITHIN GROUP is required for ordered-set aggregate mode
>        LINE 1: SELECT  mode(logins_count) AS mode_value FROM "registrations"  WHERE "registrations"."cr...
> ```

The error occurs when doing:

```
SELECT mode(logins_count) AS mode_value FROM registrations
WHERE registrations.created_at > '20141105';
```

I do not understand the error message and I do not get what I have to change?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Postgres 9.4 introduced a new subclass of aggregate functions. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)

> There is a subclass of aggregate functions called **ordered-set
> aggregates** for which an ***`order_by_clause`*** is **required**, usually because
> the aggregate's computation is only sensible in terms of a specific
> ordering of its input rows.

One of the new built-in ordered-set aggregate functions is [**`mode()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-ORDEREDSET-TABLE) which happens to collide with the name of your custom aggregate function. (The [Postgres Wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Mode) you are referring to had not been updated since 2013.)

#### Solution

Use a different name for your custom aggregate function to avoid the collision.
Or ***better*** yet: use the new built-in function instead. Read the [now updated Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Mode) for details.

Comment: I don't understand how to use `mode`, though. How is it only sensible in terms of a specific ordering? `mode` should just take a set of values and give you the mode.

Comment: You could use public.mode(logins_count) if your function is in the public schema. But actually, the implementation of PostgreSQL's mode() function is incredibly slow, slower than one written in SQL. So using your own function might be a good idea.